# Texture problem, mapping looks like washed together

Tags: texturing, uv

I am texturing a model, and i encountered this problem, which i dont know the name of so i cant google it :( 
I have marked my problem with a blue circle, it looks good at every other point, but not this one. I have tried moving the vertices & project sphere again & minimize stretches, but it just moves the problematic part to another point.

Thank you in advance.

***edit: i added another picture with the UV map.***
[image: Problem marked with blue]

[image]